# Javascript (Tampermonkey) Text Highlighter disables buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, tampermonkey

I have created a Tampermonkey script to highlight certain key information on a webpage using the Mark.js addon.

```
// @require      https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js
// @require      https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js
// @require      https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @require      http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js
// @require      https://raw.githubusercontent.com/julmot/mark.js/master/dist/mark.js
// @include     http://localhost/vortek_php/*
/* globals jQuery, $, waitForKeyElements, angular, this, Mark */
// @grant       GM_addStyle

waitForKeyElements (
    'tr',
    read_table_rows
);

function read_table_rows(){
    console.log('checkedout')
    let tr_ele = ''
    tr_ele = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for (var i = 0; i < tr_ele.length; i++) {

        // Looking for tr elements which does not have the 'mark' element

        let is_present = tr_ele[i].getElementsByTagName("mark")[0]
        if (typeof(is_present) == 'undefined' || is_present == null){
            //console.log('not present')
            var instance = new Mark(tr_ele[i]);
            instance.mark("Sta Sword bee pokemon", {
                "each": function(mark){
                    mark.setAttribute("style", "color: black; background-color: coral;");
             }
         });
            // console.log(tr_ele.textContent);
        }
    
    }

    return(false)

};
```

The website is built on Angular JS and contains ~100 rows of information. At a time, only ~15 rows are loaded and the rest are rendered on demand when the user scrolls up or down. Which is why we keep looking for the 'tr' element.

The website also includes 2 button at the end of each row,we need to review and info and select a button. The highlighter works just fine, however the buttons stop working:

```
<label _ngcontent-c10="" ngbbuttonlabel="" class="btn btn-agree ng-star-inserted">
   <input _ngcontent-c10="" ngbbutton="" type="radio" value="AGREE" ng-reflect-value="AGREE" name="decision">YES 
</label>
```

I dont exactly understand why its breaking the website, could you please help me? Is there a better approach to approach the highlighting text that is case in-sensitive and partially matches words as well?

Comment: You should link the website to facilitate testing

Comment: @PinkiePie Unfortunately, The website is not yet accessible to the public